# Get file stored to Subversion (SVN) via Checksum (SHA Hash)

Tags: svn, checksum, sha, key-value-store

Subversion info shows the checksum (SHA1 hash since 1.8) of comitted files. Is there a command to get the file info via its checksum?

I would like to (mis?)use Subversion as a Key-Value-Store.

Comment: I spent some time now trying to find this on our server. I thought the **rep_cache.db** sqlite3 database would have the answer, but it looks like these are only the deltas that Subversion's server maintain.

I know for a fact that if a repo is checked out and the checked-out revision is in that working copy, you will be able to query the **nodes** table in the working copy's **wc.db** database (found in the **.svn** directory of the working copy).